# How to get change the value of the UISlider

Tags: swift, rx-swift

How to get the values while moving the UISlider?

I'm using the following code:

**ViewModel:**

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift

final class ViewModel {

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    var value: Variable<Float>

    init() {

        self.value = Variable(Float(0.0))

    }
}
```

**ViewController:**

```
@IBOutlet var slider: UISlider!

private var viewModel: ViewModel!
private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    viewModel = ViewModel()

    slider.rx.value
        .subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
            self.viewModel.value = Variable(Float(value))
        })
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag) 
}
```

But this code does not work. What's my mistake?

Comment: What version of the RxSwift are you using?

Comment: @TrungAnhPham I'm using version 3.2

Comment: I'm just tried your code and it work (Xcode 9 beta 2, Swift 3)

Comment: @TrungAnhPham When I move the slider, the value in viewModel does not change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not tested, but I would try:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    viewModel = ViewModel()

    slider.rx.value
        .subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
            self.viewModel.value.value = Float(value) 
        })
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag) 
}
```

Also I would rename your `value` property in your `viewModel` to `sliderValue` (or whatever, but not `value`). If you do this, your code will look better:

`self.viewModel.sliderValue.value = Float(value)`

instead of

`self.viewModel.value.value = ...`

Answer (score 6):

You're replacing the Variable instead of inserting a new value into it. This is guaranteed to fail.

`ViewModel.value` should be a `let` instead of a `var`. You don't want to replace Variable, you want to assign a new value *into* it. While you are at it, make your ViewModel a struct:

```
struct ViewModel {
    let value = Variable<Float>(0)
}
```

It can be a final class if you must, but `value` should still be a `let` not a `var`.

Your `viewDidLoad` should look like this:

```
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    slider.rx.value
        .subscribe(onNext: { value in
            self.viewModel.value.value = value
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Or better yet:

```
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    slider.rx.value
        .bind(to: viewModel.value)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Or even better... Whatever is subscribing to ViewModel.value should subscribe/bind directly to slider.rx.value instead. That way you can get rid of the middleman.

Something like this:

```
public class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        slider.rx.value
            .map { "The slider's value is \($0)" }
            .bind(to: label.rx.text)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

}
```

You will see the label's text change as you move the slider.

Answer (score 3):

If you use new `BehaviorRelay` instead of old `Variable`:

```
struct MyViewModel {
    let value = BehaviorRelay<Float>(value: 0)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet var valueLabel: UILabel!
    private var viewModel = MyViewModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        slider.rx.value
            .bind(to: viewModel.value)
            .disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)

        // If you want to listen and bind to a label
        viewModel.value.asDriver()
            .map { "Value: \($0 * 100)%" }
            .drive(valueLabel.rx.text)
            .disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
    }
}
```